# How to get the number of forks of a GitHub repo with the GitHub API?

Tags: fork, github-api

I use Github API V3 to get forks count for a repository, i use:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/forks
```

The request bring me only 30 results even if a repository contain more, I googled a little and I found that due to the memory restrict the API return only 30 results per page, and if I want next results I have to specify the number of page.

Only me I don't need all this information, all  I need is the number of forks.
Is there any way to get only the number of forks?

Because If I start to loop page per page my script risque to crash if a repository contain thousand results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try and use a search query.

For instance, for my repo [VonC/b2d](https://github.com/VonC/b2d), I would use:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user%3AVonC+repo%3Ab2d+b2d

The json answer gives me a `"forks_count": 5`

Here is one with more than 4000 forks (consider only the first result, meaning the one whose "`full_name`" is actually "`strongloop/express`")

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user%3Astrongloop+repo%3Aexpress+express

```
"forks_count": 4114,
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a job where I need to **get all forks as git-remotes** of a github project.

I wrote the simple python script https://gist.github.com/urpylka/9a404991b28aeff006a34fb64da12de4

At the base of the program is recursion function for getting forks of a fork. And I met same problem (**GitHub API was returning me only 30 items**).

**I solved it with add increment  of `?page=1` and add check for null response from server.**

```
def get_fork(username, repo, forks, auth=None):

page = 1
while 1:

    r = None
    request = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/forks?page={}".format(username, repo, page)
    if auth is None: r = requests.get(request)
    else: r = requests.get(request, auth=(auth['login'], auth['secret']))
    j = r.json()
    r.close()

    if 'message' in j:
        print("username: {}, repo: {}".format(username, repo))
        print(j['message'] + " " + j['documentation_url'])
        if str(j['message']) == "Not Found": break
        else: exit(1)

    if len(j) == 0: break
    else: page += 1

    for item in j:
        forks.append({'user': item['owner']['login'], 'repo': item['name']})

        if auth is None:
            get_fork(item['owner']['login'], item['name'], forks)
        else:
            get_fork(item['owner']['login'], item['name'], forks, auth)
```